# Filling a gridview with data and radio button in each box c#

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a `Gridview2` and I want to fill it with data from the table "`contact`".
I did that but now I want that every box in my `Gridview` has a radio button.
I tried a lot but I didn't find the right solution.
Has anyone an idea?

[image]

**This the code of my method:**

```
protected void load_data()
    {


      String str1 = Label1.Text;
      String str2 = Label2.Text;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ic-webdev;Initial Catalog=intracall;User ID=sa;Password=xs4intracall";
            con.Open();

             SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [id],[firstname], [lastname],[street],[zipcode], [city],[customerNumber],[salutation], [company],[departement],[telephone] FROM contact WHERE SOUNDEX(firstname)=SOUNDEX('" + str1 + "') AND SOUNDEX(lastname)=SOUNDEX('" + str2 + "')", con);



            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ada.Fill(dt);
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            SetSelectedRecord();

            con.Close();
        }


        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

and this is the code of the `Gridview2`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="4" GridLines="Vertical" Height="160px"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="271px" ForeColor="Black" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" IsPostBack="false">
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
              <Columns > </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Did you try Item templates?

Comment: Google asp:Gridview and set up your gridview with corresponding <asp:boundfield> and <asp:TempleField>. I'm sure you will find information there. It's hard to tell you something else when you don't write WHAT you have tried. :)

Comment: surely you're looking for this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to do "select" query like following:

Comment: select [ ],[ ],... from contact where condition. And this condition depends on data in Labels in my interface. My problem is how to fill my gridview with data depending on Labels and in the same time bild radio buttons.

Comment: Manou u got solution?